How can I safely remove specific ShadCN UI components from my Next.js project without leaving residual code or dependencies?
I'm using ShadCN components in a Next.js project, and I need to remove some of the UI components that are no longer needed. I want to make sure I remove them cleanly, without leaving behind any unused imports, dependencies, or configuration that could impact my app's performance or cause errors.
Specifically, I’m unsure if I need to do more than just delete the component files from my /components/ui folder. Here are my questions:
Besides deleting the component files, are there additional steps I should take to ensure there are no unused imports or configurations left?
Are there any dependencies that might be safe to uninstall, or tools to help identify unused ones?
Any guidance on best practices for cleanly removing components in a Next.js project (with ShadCN and Tailwind CSS) would be appreciated!

Before deleting individual components from components/ui you can look for the dependencies imported within the component and uninstall them.
For example the dialog.tsx component has a @radix-ui/react-dialog dep.  You can uninstall @radix-ui/react-dialog and delete dialog.tsx to completely remove it.
Of course some dependencies may be used across different components in which case just deleting the component will be sufficient.
